# Not getting same format as stored in mysql database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, line-breaks, nl2br

I stored some data in database as :-

```
  main()
      {
           int num;
           printf("please enter a number");
      }
```

After fetching this field i want same format when i am using nl2br() function but it is showing like this :-

```
main()
{
int num;
printf("please enter a number");
}
```

i.e not taking spaces..please help me..thank you

Answer (score 0):

HTML will skip multiple spaces and new lines. While you are a ways there with nl2br, you can simply output the entire thing inside a set of `<pre>` and then ` tags which will show it EXACTLY as it is in your database.

An example would be to do this:

```
$string='Some funky
formatting with spaces and
    some additional indenting...";

echo "<pre>".$string."</pre>";
```

The output would be:

```
Some funky
formatting with spaces and
    some additional indenting...
```

Answer (score 0):

When printing multiple space characters on a web page, only one space is shown.

To preserve whitespace, you'll need to do something like this:

```
echo nl2br(str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $content));
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `<pre>` tag (pre formatted), that will use a mono spaced font and keep all the white space

```
<pre>
text goes here and here 
         and here and here            Some out here
</pre>
```